# How to calculating real dimensions using canvas and camera?

Tags: javascript, computer-vision, qr-code, pose-estimation

How can I calculate the real dimensions of an object on a plane using a camera and canvas, taking into account perspective distortion when the camera angle is changed? Currently, I have a camera facing a plane with an object on it, and I am using jsqr to obtain the coordinates of a reference QR code. I have a whiteboard layer on top of the video tag, and drawing a line with one of the sides of the QR code allows me to estimate the dimensions that are close to the real dimensions. However, I need to account for perspective distortion when the camera angle is changed. What is the best approach to achieve this?

```
{
  "topRightCorner": {
    "x": 872.5086679615921,
    "y": 810.804619872336
  },
  "topLeftCorner": {
    "x": 1153.5646618728827,
    "y": 815.8786697172964
  },
  "bottomRightCorner": {
    "x": 889.327694934698,
    "y": 604.2159830226265
  },
  "bottomLeftCorner": {
    "x": 1159.2881868528104,
    "y": 607.9004011299469
  },
  "topRightFinderPattern": {
    "x": 900.5,
    "y": 791
  },
  "topLeftFinderPattern": {
    "x": 1127.5,
    "y": 795
  },
  "bottomLeftFinderPattern": {
    "x": 1133,
    "y": 626.5
  },
  "bottomRightAlignmentPattern": {
    "x": 934,
    "y": 640
  }
}
```

current code

```
function pixelToCm (lineLength, refSize, location) {
  try {
    const refWidth = Math.max(
      Math.abs(location.topRightCorner.x - location.topLeftCorner.x),
      Math.abs(location.topRightCorner.y - location.topLeftCorner.y)
    )

    const refHeight = Math.max(
      Math.abs(location.bottomLeftCorner.x - location.topLeftCorner.x),
      Math.abs(location.bottomLeftCorner.y - location.topLeftCorner.y),
    )

    const pixelSize = refSize / Math.max(refWidth, refHeight)


    const lineLengthCm = lineLength * pixelSize

    console.log(lineLength, refSize, refWidth, refHeight, pixelSize, lineLengthCm)

    return _.round(Math.abs(lineLengthCm), 2)
  } catch {
    return 0
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you didn't say that you know the physical size of the QR code. do you or not? also: this isn't an opencv question: you don't seem to be using opencv.

Comment: yes i do know the physical size, this is a javascript client, used to opencv js version, but it looks perspective pnp should build by self.